# How to display 4 HTML elements on 2 lines (two elements each)?

Tags: html, css

I want to figure out how to have a phone icon and a phone number in one line. The same goes for an email icon and an email address. I want to have two lines.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #20b2aa;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.info {
  background: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

#phoneNumber, #emailAddress {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

img {
  background: red;
}

p {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Contact Me</h1>
<div class="info">
  <h3>Eugene</h3>
  <img id="phoneImage" src="img/phone.png">
  <p id="phoneNumber">(800) 123-4000</p>
  <img id="envelopeImage" src="img/envelope.png" alt="">
  <p id="emailAddress">someaddress@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

Here's the screenshot of what I have so far:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: make img and p tag to display inline;

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to write markup for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an un-ordered list and add the icon and text to the list item in some way. That could be a `img` inside the `li` with text next to it or you could go a more CSS route with the icons as pseudo elements. This way, if you need to re-use the icons/contact format elsewhere you only need to add a class to the `li`.

```css
.contact-info {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.contact-info .phone::before,
.contact-info .email::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.contact-info .phone::before {
  background-image: url( 'http://placehold.it/10x10/fc0' );
}

.contact-info .email::before {
  background-image: url( 'http://placehold.it/10x10/' );
}
```

```html
<h1>Contact Me</h1>

<h3>Eugene</h3>
<ul class="contact-info">
  <li class="phone">(800) 123-4000</li>
  <li class="email">someaddress@gmail.com</li>
</ul>
```